# Is there a pg_hba.conf at Azure?

Tags: postgresql, azure

Sometimes the pg log would say `no pg_hba.conf entry for ...`. I've not been able to locate this file for pg at Azure. Can someone tell me where it is?

Comment: If azure differs from the standard Postgres installation, you should probably consult the azure documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is on the database server, out of your reach. But perhaps they offer a web interface that allows you to configure it; check the documentation.

If you have the permissions, you can use [`pg_hba_file_rules`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-hba-file-rules.html) to examine the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Azure PostgresSQL Flexible Server you cannot access the file. (I believe same is true for single server, but I could not verify it).

> Because Azure Database for PostgreSQL is a managed database service, users are not provided host or OS access to view or modify configuration files such as pg_hba.conf. The content of the files is automatically updated based on the network settings.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-networking

The view [`pg_hba_file_rules`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-hba-file-rules.html) (version 10 an above) or query (up to version 9.6) `SELECT pg_read_file('pg_hba.conf');` ([source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/181639/how-do-i-query-the-running-pg-hba-configuration/181641#181641)) do not work due to missing permissions.

You can set firewall rules from Azure Panel or CLI, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-firewall-rules